# android:how to move widget at a specific position in graphical screen via drag and drop

Tags: android

I am quite new to android development please enlighten me on this
how to move widgets like button, textviews etc at a specific position in graphical screen via drag and drop..

Thanks in advance

Akshat

Comment: Please see my answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try Following Code:-

```
int x_cord, y_cord;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v == mImageViewEye1) {
            System.out.println("Eye1 is Clicked...");
            layoutParams1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mImageViewEye1
                    .getLayoutParams();
            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
                scaleimage(layoutParams1);
                layoutParams1.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
                mImageViewEye1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void scaleimage(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams) {
        if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
            x_cord = windowwidth;
        }
        if (y_cord > windowheight) {
            y_cord = windowheight;
        }
        layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
        layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
    }
```

If u have any Query then Tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You would detect drag movement in View.onTouchEvent.
Then you may interpret movement and apply it to widget.

You can use View.setAnimation to change position where widget is drawn. But it probably won't change its real location, so touches will still occur on previous position.

Or you can modify widget's LayoutParams, but instance of real LayoutParams applied to View depend on parent ViewGroup where widget is added. Easiest would be to store your widgets in AbsoluteLayout, and change position in AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams, where position is plain x/y.